# Algorithm for Alternate merge strings in rust

Tags: string, algorithm, rust, merge, rust-cargo

Here is my code for alternate merge string in rust. I am not getting the expected output. It works fine for equal length strings. Issue is when we have unequal strings it skips one character.

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn merge_alternately(word1: String, word2: String) -> String {
        let mut merged = String::new();
        let mut chars1 = word1.chars();
        let mut chars2 = word2.chars();

        while let (Some(c1), Some(c2)) = (chars1.next(), chars2.next()) {
            merged.push(c1);
            merged.push(c2);
        }
        // Append any remaining characters from word1
        while let Some(c1) = chars1.next() {
            merged.push(c1);
        }

        // Append any remaining characters from word2
        while let Some(c2) = chars2.next() {
            merged.push(c2);
        }
        merged
    }
}
```

Here is test case failure:

Input
word1 =
"ab"
word2 =
"pqrs"

Current Output
"apbqs"

Expected Output
"apbqrs"

Comment: When your first loop ends with `(None, Some(..)`, you drop the character and lose it.

Comment: Replaced while let with this simple solution :

 'code'

loop{
            let chars1 = chars1_iter.next();
            let chars2 = chars2_iter.next();

            if let Some(i) = chars1 {
                merged.push(i);
            }
            if let Some(i) = chars2 {
                merged.push(i);
            }
            if chars1.is_none() && chars2.is_none() {
                break
            }
        }

Comment: @HamzaSajid if that solves your problem you should make it an answer (use the box below. If it's to clarify your question you should [edit] it instead of adding info as a comment.

Comment: Consider unifying those in a nice `match` statement.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning how to [step through your code with a debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/rust#_debugging). It's pretty obvious what's wrong when looking at what exactly is happening step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while let (Some(c1), Some(c2))` doesn't doesn't match if only one of the two returns a character. This causes said character to be skipped.

Your three `while let` loops can me merged to a single `loop{match}`, requiring all cases to be handled properly:

```rust
pub fn merge_alternately(word1: String, word2: String) -> String {
    let mut merged = String::new();
    let mut chars1 = word1.chars();
    let mut chars2 = word2.chars();

    loop {
        match (chars1.next(), chars2.next()) {
            (Some(c1), Some(c2)) => merged.extend([c1, c2]),
            (Some(c1), None) => merged.push(c1),
            (None, Some(c2)) => merged.push(c2),
            (None, None) => break,
        }
    }

    merged
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", merge_alternately("ab".into(), "pqrs".into()));
}
```

```
apbqrs
```

---

Further, if you are allowed to use libraries, the pretty much standard library for iterators is [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools). It has an [`.interleave()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.interleave) function which does exactly what you need:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

pub fn merge_alternately(word1: String, word2: String) -> String {
    word1.chars().interleave(word2.chars()).collect()
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", merge_alternately("ab".into(), "pqrs".into()));
}
```

```
apbqrs
```